# Checking an array list against another array list

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, boolean

This is a method in a spell checker. As the header explains, it should return true if and only if all the words added to the arraylist are found in the parent array, words. Otherwise it should return a false value. I've been fighting with this for a few hours and this is my current situation...

```
    /**
    * This method returns true if (and only if) all words in the
    * given wordList are found in the dictionary.
    */
    public boolean allKnown(ArrayList<String> wordList)
    {
        boolean result = true;
        for(int index = 0; index < wordList.size(); index++)
        {
            if(words.contains(!wordList.contains(index)))
            {
                result = false;
            }
        result = true;
        }
    return result;
    }
```

All I really need is a way to turn out a yes or no, but I'm lost.
Please try and work with the code given as this is an exercise to teach that code.
Thanks!

Comment: make a copy of the ArrayList you are testing then copy.removeAll(known) and test the size of the copy if 0 everything in copy was in known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out `result = true;` - you don't want to reset the value to `true` at every step in the loop.

Also change `wordList.contains` to `wordList.get` (because you want to get the word at a specific index, not check if it's contained in `wordList`) and move the `!` out (because you can't 'not' a string).

And you can also optimize by checking `result`'s value in the for-loop condition (or simply returning directly in the if-statement).

```
public boolean allKnown(ArrayList<String> wordList)
{
    boolean result = true;
    for(int index = 0; index < wordList.size() && result; index++)
    {
        if(!words.contains(wordList.get(index)))
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If `words` really is an array and not an `ArrayList`, it doesn't have a `contains` method, you'll have to either have a double for-loop, or convert it to a list:

```
  List<String> parentWords = Arrays.asList(words);
  ...
  if (parentWords.contains(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
if(words.contains(!wordList.contains(index)))
```

`!wordList.contains(index)` is a boolean expression, so it always evaluates to either `true` or `false`. So you're actually checking if the `words` list contains true or false, not the word like you want. Replace it with `if(!words.contains(wordList.get(index))` to check if the current word is found in the dictionary.

I would suggest a following solution: iterate `wordList` word by word, and for each word check if it's found in the dictionary. If not so, return false immediately. If you reach the end of the loop, return true.

Answer (score 2):

Here could be another solution:

```java
public static boolean allKnown(List<String> parent, List<String> child) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(child);
    temp.removeAll(parent);
    return temp.isEmpty();
}
```

For example:

```java
List<String> parent = Arrays.asList("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4");
List<String> childOk = Arrays.asList("w1", "w4");
List<String> childKo = Arrays.asList("w1", "xx");
System.out.println(allKnown(parent, childOk));
System.out.println(allKnown(parent, childKo));
```

Prints:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reset result to true after your if. Because like this the whole function will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. Don't use `ArrayList` as a method parameter, always use the more abstract `List` (none of your code depends on `ArrayList`, so you can change the implementation later, if you like).
2. Iterate over `List` objects using the simplified syntax shown below.
3. You only need one word to be not in the `words` list to return `false`, so do exactly that (as shown below).

```
public boolean allKnown(List<String> wordList) {
    for (String word : wordList) {
        if (!words.contains(word)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean allKnown(ArrayList<String> wordList)
{
    boolean result = true;
    for(String word : wordList)
    {
        if(!words.contains(word))
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version :

```
public boolean allKnown(List<String> wordList) {
   List<String> wordListCopy = new ArrayList<String>(wordList);
   return !wordListCopy.retainAll(words);
}
```

**PS :** `retainAll()` removes from you `wordList` all of its elements that are not contained in you `dictionnary`. This method return **true** if your `wordList` changed as a result of the call (after removing the non existing element), in other word, this method return false when all your `wordList` elements exists in you `dictionnary`.